# Platform not supported when running `npm run flow`

Tags: node.js, flowtype

I am on Ubuntu 14.04. Node version is `4.5.0`. `npm` version is `2.15.9`.

I have `flow-bin` version `0.32.0` in my `package.json` development dependencies:

```
$ cat package.json | grep flow-bin
"flow-bin": "^0.32.0",
```

The `flow-bin` package is locally available:

```
$ npm ls --depth 0 | grep flow
serverside-node-babel-mocha-flow@1.0.0 /home/mperdikeas/test-project
├── babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@6.14.0
├── flow-bin@0.32.0
```

My `npm run flow` target is:

```
cat package.json |  grep \"flow\"
"flow": "flow; test $? -eq 0 -o $? -eq 2",
```

When I run `npm run flow` I get the following trace:

```
$ npm run flow

> serverside-node-babel-mocha-flow@1.0.0 flow /home/mperdikeas/test-project
> flow; test $? -eq 0 -o $? -eq 2

/home/mperdikeas/test-project/node_modules/flow-bin/cli.js:20
  throw new Error('Platform not supported.');
    ^

Error: Platform not supported.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mperdikeas/test-project/node_modules/flow-bin/cli.js:20:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-62-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "flow"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! serverside-node-babel-mocha-flow@1.0.0 flow: `flow; test $? -eq 0 -o $? -eq 2`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the serverside-node-babel-mocha-flow@1.0.0 flow script 'flow; test $? -eq 0 -o $? -eq 2'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the serverside-node-babel-mocha-flow package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     flow; test $? -eq 0 -o $? -eq 2
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs serverside-node-babel-mocha-flow
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls serverside-node-babel-mocha-flow
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/mperdikeas/test-project/npm-debug.log
```

When I directly run flow from the shell (without using `npm` and `package.json`) I get an identical trace:

```
$ ./node_modules/flow-bin/vendor/flow
/home/mperdikeas/test-project/node_modules/flow-bin/cli.js:20
  throw new Error('Platform not supported.');
    ^

Error: Platform not supported.
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mperdikeas/test-project/node_modules/flow-bin/cli.js:20:9)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mperdikeas/test-project/node_modules/flow-bin/vendor/flow:16:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

What is the meaning of this message, i.e. which platform is not supported? and how can I fix that?

My other targets, (e.g. `npm run test` and `npm run start`) work fine. It seems that this is Flow-related.

Comment: Please take a look at https://github.com/flowtype/flow-bin/blob/669513d905fd67fad3035f8837f29b8d66128139/index.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flow requires a 64 bit operating system. Is it possible you're running a 32 bit version of Ubuntu?

https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/270 has some context on why Flow currently requires 64 bit.

Comment: Yes, that was a 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 system. The same setup worked in a 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 system without problems.